# object doesn't support this property or method document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, browser

I'm testing one line code on IE7 but it's giving me the following error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method and it refers to

Here's the problem line in question:

```
var checked = document.querySelector('[name="answer1"]:checked');
```

This is the whole code

**Question1 : did you like the training?**

```
<input name="q4" value="Yes" type="radio"> Yes
<input name="q4" value="No" type="radio"> No
<br>
<button id="getval">cick here</button>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.getElementById('getval').onclick = function() {
    var checked = document.querySelector('[name="q4"]:checked');
    alert(checked ? checked.value : 'Not selected');
}
</script>
```

Is there anyway to fix that?

Comment: which version of IE ? all IE ?

Comment: I have similar problem in IE10... Any ideas?

Comment: @KirillKobelev - you probably have a different problem, as the issue here is that `querySelector()` is only supported in IE8+.

Comment: Thanks. I figured this out... Browser was forced to emulate IE7..

Answer (score 4):

`querySelector` is [only available in IE8+](http://caniuse.com/queryselector). To query by selector in IE7 you'll need something like [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), which is a standalone version of the CSS query-by-selector code that's built into jquery.  Or if you prefer something a bit lighter and more seamless you could use a polyfill such as the one [described here](https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/blob/master/polyfill.js#L655), like so:

```
if (!document.querySelectorAll) {
  document.querySelectorAll = function (selectors) {
    var style = document.createElement('style'), elements = [], element;
    document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(style);
    document._qsa = [];

    style.styleSheet.cssText = selectors + '{x-qsa:expression(document._qsa && document._qsa.push(this))}';
    window.scrollBy(0, 0);
    style.parentNode.removeChild(style);

    while (document._qsa.length) {
      element = document._qsa.shift();
      element.style.removeAttribute('x-qsa');
      elements.push(element);
    }
    document._qsa = null;
    return elements;
  };
}

if (!document.querySelector) {
  document.querySelector = function (selectors) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selectors);
    return (elements.length) ? elements[0] : null;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

old IE doesn't have `querySelector`. You have to use an engine, like sizzle (that's what's in jQuery), zest, etc

Comment: You can also loop through the elements to find the ones matching

Answer (score 1):

In IE 9+ css3 selector like the one you are using are supported ..

http://caniuse.com/queryselector

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [creating-a-queryselector-for-ie-that-runs-at-native-speed](http://ajaxian.com/archives/creating-a-queryselector-for-ie-that-runs-at-native-speed)
and [adding-document-queryselectorall-support-to-ie-7](http://www.codecouch.com/2012/05/adding-document-queryselectorall-support-to-ie-7/)

Okay, you can use jquery $('#selector') as that equals queryselector and you can include jQuery for that.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.